# Spring 4 - websocket messaging stomp handler

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-4

I was trying the tutorial provided by spring  - [messaging-stomp-websocket](https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) and it is working fine

Now I want to extend the this and add my WebSocket handler which intercept the channel.

```
public class WebSocketHandlerSpring extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) {
    }
}
```

This handler to WebSocketConfig class.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
    }        
}
```

Any help how to configure `WebSocketHandlerSpring` handler to `WebSocketConfig` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raw `WebSocketHandler` support comes from `@EnableWebSocket` (not `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker`). You need to add that and implement `WebSocketConfigurer` to register your endpoints. Example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-tests/spring-boot-smoke-tests/spring-boot-smoke-test-websocket-tomcat/src/main/java/smoketest/websocket/tomcat/SampleTomcatWebSocketApplication.java).

Comment: thnaks and impressive

Comment: The page does not exist, can you update ur answer?